# Is it possible to use the return values of one if-statement as a condition in another?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was wondering if it'd be possible to have the return value of one `if-else` used as a condition in another `if-else`.

In the first if-else, `img` in `file2.js`, there's one variable returned at any given point.

In the second if-else, `link` in `file3.js`, I'm attempting to use the output of `img` as part of `link`'s conditions.

I've tried using `=` and `===`, but that has proved to only load the first and last result of `link`'s return values, respectively.

```
<!-- file1.html is only included for context and AFAIK, doesn't really affect my question: -->

<script async src="file2.js"></script>
<p>
    <a target="_blank" href="file3.html" id="aTarg" name="aTarg">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4LtRreH.png" id="pic" name="pic"/>
        </a>
</p>
<p>....more article text</p>



/* file2.js */

const now = new Date();
 const timeNoon = now.getHours() === 12;

const CallingS1 = "https://i.imgur.com/5IaY11U.png";
const CallingS2 = "https://i.imgur.com/ANdRs50.png";

let img = function() {
    if (timeNoon) {
        return CallingS1;
    } else {
        return CallingS2;
    }
}
// function imgLink() works well:

function imgLink() {
    document.getElementById('pic').src=img();
}

imgLink();


<!-- file3.html: -->

<head>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
<script>
/* Here is where the problem's begin. I'm trying to use the output of img (in file2.js) be the conditions for link() */
  function link() { 
    if (img === CallingS1) {
        return location.replace("https://www.google.com/");
    } else if (img === CallingS2) {
        return location.replace("https://www.bing.com/");
    } else {
        return location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="link()">
</body>
```

I'm trying to have `function link()` rely on the outputs of `let img = function()`.

Comment: Thought of this just as I posted: Put one `if` condition in a function, set each to variables: `let img1 = function() { if (condition) {} }`. Then call each `img` in an if-else from file3.html: `if (img1 === true) {}`. 

All guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You are testing if a Function equals a string not the result of the Function call.

Comment: Note that an if statement doesn't have a return value. Instead a function has a return value. Understanding this terminology will help you reason better about your code. As the answer below suggests, you need to call the function in order to get its return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img` is a function. just call it, for example:

```
function link() { 
  const imgRes = img();
  if (imgRes === CallingS1) {
    return location.replace("https://www.google.com/");
  } else if (imgRes === CallingS2) {
    return location.replace("https://www.bing.com/");
  } else {
    return location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah you're correct, this worked. Thanks for the help.